# Angular2 cannot read value of undefined input text

Tags: angular, text, input, import, components

I have had some issues with input type text, it says cannot read value of undefined when i pass the value through a button( of course it is filled in).

```
<a class="btn btn-default" (click)="approveClick(reviewerInput.value)">Goedkeuren</a>
...
<input #reviewerInput type="text">
```

ts file :

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
...
approveClick(value: string): void {
        this.proposal.Status = "Approved";
        this.proposal.Reviewer = value;
}
```

Is it because im missing an import or ? 
Kind regards!

Comment: Where/when exactly does it say `cannot read value of undefined`?

Comment: `<a class="btn btn-default" (click)="approveClick(reviewerInput.value)">Goedkeuren</a>
` There it says it @AJT_82

Comment: Is it maybe because the variable isnt defined yet, so it has to be in front of the button? @AJT_82

Comment: Seems to work fine here ;) http://plnkr.co/edit/2v6cXHVB4pzoVNpjd3dH?p=preview What do you mean *"has to be in front of button?"*

Comment: Ahh, I had to put my input before the hyperlink, so it exists before I call it. Thank you very much for the help! @AJT_82

Comment: input before the hyperlink? Do you mean in the template? It doesn't matter, and even in the plunker I don't have it before the hyperlink ;) Did you solve it... I fell off the wagon now I think :D

Comment: stupid mistake of me but the hyperlink was in a ´<div><a></div><div><input></div>` so they didnt know eachother. I forgot to mention this because i thought it had no influence so sorry .... @AJT_82